# Are Matrix.org questions in-topic? Also about Tag #matrix.org

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to discuss about questions related to `#matrix.org`, and discussing about a new related Tag for SuperUser.

### What is Matrix.org

The [Matrix.org](https://matrix.org/) is an Open Source, decentralized, distributed, **chat protocol** to have private and group conversations. It supports easy interconnection to IRC, and server-side applications to bridge Matrix.org users to Telegram, Slack and so on.

### Adoption and notability

Matrix.org has a lot of official and not-official Open Source chat clients. The most famous is probably Element.io, available on Android Android Enthusiasts (also from F-Droid), iOS, and Linux desktop (also via snap) and also as web application.

https://matrix.org/clients/

About the notability of the project, I don't think it's something that will disappear after tomorrow. For instance, in 2020 they received 5 million dollars of donations just from Automattic (company behind WordPress).

https://matrix.org/blog/2020/05/21/welcoming-automattic-to-matrix

### Adoption inside Super User

I think questions related to some Matrix software and networking can be in-topic questions in Super User.

First of all, questions related to these command line interface software clients:

- https://github.com/tulir/gomuks (900 stars)
- https://github.com/poljar/weechat-matrix (800 stars)
- https://github.com/8go/matrix-commander (300 stars)
- https://github.com/saadsolimanxyz/matrixcli (100 stars)

Also, I think questions related to network bridges and application services can be in-topic:

- https://matrix.org/bridges/
- https://www.matrix.org/docs/guides/application-services

What else?

### Current adoption inside Stack Exchange

At the moment this topic is not very present in Stack Exchange.

In my opinion because it is too difficult to figure out where you can ask something related to Matrix.

### Proposed description for the tag

If a Tag could be useful, this could be its description:

> Matrix.org is an open, decentralized, distributed protocol. In-topic questions include: usage and fix on desktop clients, servers (in non-business environment), or "Matrix Application Services". Off-topic questions include: usage and fix on specific web client (ask in WebApps); programming over this protocol (ask in StackOverflow); server-side errors on a Matrix server in a business environment (ask in ServerFault); using or fixing a Matrix Android app (ask in Android).

### Proposed in-topic notes on Stack Exchange sister projects

The [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) network can host in-topic questions related to a very specific web-app of the Matrix protocol, like https://app.element.io/. For this case I would suggest to propose in that network a new tag `#element.io` (not to be discussed there).

The [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) network can host in-topic questions about software programming related to implementations of a Matrix.org client, SDK, or something like that. For this case I would suggest to propose in that network a new tag `#matrix.org` (not to be discussed there).

The [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) network can host in-topic questions about how to fix server-side errors in business environments related to hosting a Matrix node. For this case I would suggest to propose in that network a new tag `#matrix.org` (not to be discussed there).

The [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) network can host in-topic questions about how to use or fix a particular app on your Android device related to the Matrix protocol. For this case I would suggest to propose in that network a new tag `#matrix.org` (not to be discussed there).

What do you think about?

Comment: Android clients would also be explicitly off topic here.

Comment: [Android.se] would also not allow programming or development questions.

Comment: Thanks @Mokubai. I've integrated again. BTW feel free to edit directly

Comment: It might help for you to read the various on topic pages for the sites you are proposing: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic, https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic,  https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Serverfault is for "managing information technology systems in a business environment", not just *any* server/client based application. As it stands though, I'm not particularly fond of this tag in general.

Comment: The most important thing is: are there any existing questions related to this? Note that tags cannot exist without any questions.

Comment: Quite a few of the moderation team is aware of matrix. On SU's scope it feels like questions ought to be specific to clients and those would be more relevant. Matrix does have multiple client and server implementations after all.

Comment: @Mokubai I've explicited the business notes for SF, thanks. Again please just feel free to edit on yourself.
[@]andrew-t I started this discussion since it was not clear to me if SU was the right place to start some kind of questions. Also because there were no tags around.

Comment: (Can you please clean all the comments that are already integrated? Also this comment, thanks)

Comment: What I don't understand is why negative votes, instead of responses with a different opinion. This has a #discussion Tag after all. I am doing my best to integrate everything and this is my first post here.

Comment: Hi boz...I think the real fruit of your labour lies in the 'Proposed description for the tag'. Now much debate can surround this, but it would require a mission improbable of global consensus. Because people are always on the move, I wouldn't want anybody to get left behind, which is why I think people like coming up with "guidelines". Next I will share your concept about communities with my local. ( )_|T; noface94